# Python pandas not adding correct order of tuple to new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe that I sorted by the points column:

```
      name    points
0  vanessa     8.6
3    james     8.3
2     mike     7.2
1     mark     6.3
4  charles     5.5
```

I tried to create a new column with a rank using:

```
df['rank']=pd.Series(tuple(range(1,6)))
```

I got:

```
      name   points  rank
0  vanessa     8.6     1
3    james     8.3     4
2     mike     7.2     3
1     mark     6.3     2
4  charles     5.5     5
```

Which is not what I wanted. I solved it using df.rank():

```
df['rank']=df.points.rank(ascending=False).astype(int)
```

Then I got:

```
      name   points  rank
0  vanessa     8.6     1
3    james     8.3     2
2     mike     7.2     3
1     mark     6.3     4
4  charles     5.5     5
```

The thing is:

Why does my first attemptive using `df['rank']=pd.Series(tuple(range(1,6)))` didn't work?

Comment: because like this you are using the index to add new values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is if no index are specified in `Series`, pandas create default `RangeIndex` - `0,1,2,..len(df)`.

Solution is add parameter `index` for matching data to original:

```
df['rank']=pd.Series(tuple(range(1,6)), index=df.index)
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because of the series assigning the values according to the index values. When you are using `df['rank']=pd.Series(tuple(range(1,6)))` the values are being assigned according to the index. Check your output:

```
      name   points  rank
0  vanessa     8.6     1 #First value, to the smallest index-value
3    james     8.3     4 #Fourth value, to the fourth smallest index-value
2     mike     7.2     3 #Third value, to the third smallest index-value
1     mark     6.3     2 #Second value, to the second smallest index-value
4  charles     5.5     5 #Fifth value, to the fifth smallest index-value
```

You can work your away round using `reset_index()` followed by a `set_index()`:

```
df = df.reset_index()
df['rank'] = pd.Series(tuple(range(1,6)))
df = df.set_index('index')
```

Answer (score 1):

pd.Series(...) produces its own index from 0 to 4 inclusive.

```
df['rank'] = pd.Series(tuple(range(1,6)))
```

you actually assign in accordance with this index. 
You can pass just a simple values' list (with a correct length, equal to the *len(df)*), not a pd.Series instead.

Answer (score 0):

by addition column with Series it will assign data base on index, that is reason you got that result 
*using concat also you can achieve same result*

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data=[['vanessa',8.6],['james',8.3],['mike',7.2],['mark',6.3],['charles',5.5]],columns=['name','points'])
df1=pd.DataFrame(tuple(range(1,6)),columns=['Rank'])   # create one more datframe
df=pd.concat([df,df1],axis=1).sort_values(by=['Rank']) #concatinte by column and then sort data by Rank
```